# Get Double values from my Select Form using Vuejs

Tags: laravel, select, vue.js

I put here a picture to see my Vue App. 
 In my Select form, i have two values : 
-$keys which get me the amout referenced to my id 
-$values which get me the ID in my options.

I wrote my code like that :

```
 <select data-validation="number"  class="form-control" style="width:200px" v-model="cash.bank">
      @foreach ($users as $keys => $values)
   <option value="{{ $keys }}" >  {{ $values }}</option> 
      @endforeach
 </select>
```

My v-model=cash.bank return the value of $keys.  i need to return also for cash.id the value of $value.

My double post and put function script :

```
  addCash: function () {
        axios.post('/addglentrycash', this.cash)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                if (response.data.etat) {
                    this.cash = {
                         id: 0,
                          codeentry: response.data.etat.codeentry,
                          description: response.data.etat.description,
                          cash: response.data.etat.cash,   
                    };
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('errors: ', error)
            })
   updateBank:function(){
     axios.put('/updatebank', this.cash)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.etat) {
                this.cash = {    
                        id: (I need to write something)
                        cash: response.data.etat.cash,
                        bank:response.data.etat.bank, 
                    };   
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('errors: ', error)
            })
    },
```

This is my vue app :
[image]

Comment: it's not clear what you want